# Regex: greedy quantifier behaving lazy

Tags: c#, regex

.NET implementation of Regex defines the '?' character as a greedy quantifier that informs its expression to match 0 or 1 times and to prefer 1 if possible.

Consider the following source text:

```
some text (some parenthetical text)
```

And the following regex:

```
\A(.+)(?:\s\(.+\))?$
```

The result should be one matching group with the value:

```
some text
```

Instead, it is the whole line. Now when I remove from the regex the greedy 0 or 1 quantifier '?', I do get the expected result. However, since my requirements expect the parenthetical text may not exist, I can't leave that 0 or 1 quantifier off. How do I force it to be greedy?

Comment: I see _three_, not one matching groups in your regex.  Most regex matching engines give you the entire string as the first match.  Try taking matches 2 through 4.

Comment: You could just make the first capturing group lazy - `\A(.+?)(?:\s\(.+\))?$`.

Comment: if i understood you question, do you want to return what ever is not in the parenthesis. right? you have 2 "some" and "text" which makes me little bit confused. can you provide one or two more cases.

Comment: Josh, thanks for your solution. That works and its what I did as a work around. However, I'm more interested in getting .NET to do what it says it should be doing. Workarounds are definitely useful but I'm trying to understand why its not working in the first place. Also, if there is no good answer for this problem, I'll still accept your answer so if you want, submit it and I'll mark it.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the warning. I exclude the trivial matching groups so that isn't the problem. I appreciate the correction though.

Comment: @user1807768 it is doing what it should be doing. I believe you have a misunderstanding on how that's supposed to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't match the way you think it will is because `(.+)` is greedy.

Let me explain:

`(.+)` is greedy so it will immediately match the entire string.

`(?:\s\(.+\))?` is also greedy *however* just because something is *greedy* it doesn't mean that it *has* to match if it doesn't have too.

Take this example:

**string**: `abc123`

**regex**: `(.+)(\d{3})?`

`.+` will start out matching `abc123`. The regex engine will get to the next character (which is an empty character) and see this `(\d{3})?`. Now, the regex engine will prefer to match `\d{3}` if possible but it has already matched the entire string. Since `\d{3}` is *technically* optional, it can throw it away.

Your best bet is to make the first section lazy and keep the last section greedy.

`\A(.+)(?:\s\(.+\))?$` will become `\A(.+?)(?:\s\(.+\))?$`

`(.+?)` will try to match as few characters as possible so it leaves room for the second half but if that second half is not needed it'll consume the rest of the string.

Here's [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hT7aD1/1) with an example (I changed `\A` to `^` so multiline would work)

Comment: Ya, its obvious now that you pointed it out. Doesn't matter if I force the last subexpression to be greedy, the first greedy expression captured it.

Comment: @user1807768 bingo. Glad I could help ^^

Comment: The explanation *keep the last section lazy* is not inline with the suggested pattern. Technically optional means a subpattern can match an empty string. Note that .NET works correctly with patterns having both lazy and greedy subpatterns

Comment: @stribizhev ahh you're right. slip of the mind. Thank you, i'll edit it.

Comment: Actually, I did not downvote, but your regex is not good. It is only good if there is one parenthetical substring inside.

Comment: @stribizhev I believe that was op's situation. He only seemed interested in why his regular expression was not parsing the way he thought it would. After some explanation it seems to have helped.

Comment: Yes, just `.*` and `.+` are subpatterns that should be avoided *in the middle of a regex* whenever possible. In most cases, it is not even good to use it at the start of the pattern. With regex, one must try to keep it specific as possible. Why not use `(?:\s\([^()]+\))?` instead of `(?:\s\(.+\))?`? It seems in line with the requirements. Although OP did not precise what the parenthetical text can  include. If it can include other `(` or `)` then there is no way but use `.`. Ok, you got my voice :)

Comment: @stribizhev perhaps I should just keep the `(.+)?` to be as general and open as possible? Since op didn't did add what kind of text can be inside of the parenthesis I would hate to make a change to the regex that would break randomly in some cases. Though, I do understand why you suggest `([^()]+)?` as an alternative.

Comment: Negated character classes are more efficient than greedy dot matching in most cases. I am not sure it is this very case here

Comment: @stribizhev i understand they are more efficient but since we don't know if the parenthesis *could* contain more parenthetical characters maybe just leave `(.+)` as is?